# Add the Settings.Bundle package to a Flash CS5.5 IPA iPad Application

Tags: flash, ipad, settings.bundle, flash-cs5

we are currently developing an application in flash for the iPad. We are looking for a way to include the package "Settings.bundle"which allows to include custom settings for this application. Do you know how we can do that ? With Adobe CS5.5 of course.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this post is old but I wanted to post this answer in case someone else has this question:

Robert Hall gave a very nice answer to this on the Adobe forums: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4320963